# Elasticsearch Docker Container Stops 10secs After Start in Ubuntu

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I ran a docker-compose file to setup elasticsearch and Kibana on Ubuntu 18.04LTS. Kibana container is up and running just fine but elasticsearch goes down after about 10secs. I have restarted the containers and docker service several times and still got the same result. Been on this all day and hoping that I get some help.

Docker-Compose file.

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: es-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.audit.enabled=true
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=secretpassword
    networks:
      - es-net
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  kibana:
    container_name: kb-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.3
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-container:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=secretpassword
    networks:
      - es-net
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
networks:
  es-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Also checked the logs on the `es-container` and it displayed;

> Created elasticsearch keystore in
> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore

Comment: Bring es-container logs. Likely, you'll find the answer there pretty quick.

Comment: @YuriG what I found wasn't helpful. But when I ran docker-compose up with out '-d', I got the message that it exited with code 137

Answer (score 0):

Audit logging can be only [enabled with paid ES subscription](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/enable-audit-logging.html) and you don't provide any license info to your container.

Comment: I need to try it out first before I pay for it. I think it's got to do with memory allocation cos it exists with code 137. I know how to extend the memory on docker for windows. but not on ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the reference [docker-compose](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) you'll need `bootstrap.memory_lock: true` and `"ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"` at least.